# How to insert array in column of mysql table with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP. I need to INSERT arrays in columns of mySQL table!

I explode array and then implode three arrays with IPs, providers and countries inside.

```
$arr = file( $file,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
 foreach ( $arr as $val){
 $temp = explode(',',$val);
 $ip_arr[] = implode(',',[$temp[0]]);
 $country_arr[] = implode(',',[$temp[1]]);
 $prov_arr[] = implode(',',[$temp[2]]);
}
```

Now I need to INSERT this arrays to MYSQL columns.
Can anybody advice me something?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) will be more than sufficient to solve your issue.